# Grid is not visible in scene Xcode

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit

The grid is not visible in the scene window. even though Editor -> Enable grid is checked.
Please help me make it show again.

[image]

UPDATE: If I press the "add editor on the right" the grid appears.
[image]

and If I close the newly added editor the grid disappears again.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted Xcode and now it works :)